# Bindings in AngularJs 1.x - where are they used?

Tags: angularjs

We were [hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269601/controlleras-pattern-var-vm-this-scope-not-defined-since-update-to-angularj) by an old breaking change in our legacy AngularJs application which we won't update to Angular >2 soon.

Since AngularJs 1.6 `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled` was set to '**true**' by default but up there was an option to set it to '**false**'.

With AngularJs 1.7 this behaviour isn't allowed anymore.

So we have to check where we are using **bindings in components/directives** to use the new **$onInit** function which is called once all bindings are available for sure.

Since we don't use `.component` but `.directive` only:

Is it true, that we only have to apply this change for all directives which are using `bindToController: true`?

Or which other cases might be forced to consider?

**Update** for clarification:

1. I understand that we have to change/upgrade to make it work and why.
2. What I am not perfectly understanding (and didn't see it in the suggested duplicate either): When not using components at all, where does this change affect us? Is ot only when we directives with bindToController: true or are there others (potentially less intuitive like using $scope in a specific way/context etc.). From reading the upgrade instructions we only got the component example.

Comment: Relevant, other SO post where the answer describes migrating AngularJS versions, for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937725/angularjs-compileprovider-preassignbindingsenabled-is-not-a-function

Comment: From that post "The flag controlled whether bindings were available inside the controller constructor or only in the $onInit hook." -- I think it's safe to say one of your answers (do we only have to make this update to directives bound to a controller) is therefore *yes*.

Comment: On 1July2018, support for AngularJS 1.6 ended. We strongly recommend migrating your applications to not rely on it as soon as possible. For more information, see [AngularJS MISC - Version Support Status](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status).

Comment: @georgeawg, kindly see my update, i don't see the duplicatr, because I understood why and how - I am specifically asking for the where.

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg, duplicate's question is about bindToController too. So nothing else to consider then?

Comment: I'm voting to keep this question closed as in addition to being answered by duplicates, the question is too broad. If those answers do not fully address your question, [please ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. Limit the question to a problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am really sorry, if it's my English or my limited understanding. There is only one question: Is it enough to deql with bindToController: true Directives? I found no other example proving me wrong so far. Can you confirm? Or how should I rephrase the questuon?

Comment: @gregawg, i guess i got it now, i rephrased summary. Again: I am not asking when and why to upgrade!

Comment: OK, created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274406/upgrade-angularjs-1-5-to-1-6-which-exact-bindings-are-affected-by-change-in-c) trying to be as specific as possible. Should I delete this one?