# Upgrade AngularJs 1.5 to 1.6 - which exact bindings are affected by change in $compile reg controller instances?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components, angularjs-1.6

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$compile) for a change in $compile when upgrading from AngularJs 1.5 to 1.6 states:

> pre-assigning bindings on component/directive controller instances is disabled by default, which means that they will no longer be available inside the constructors.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.6 - $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$compile)

The upgrade example in the documentation is as follows (shortened):

**Before**

```
.component('myComponent', {
  bindings: {value: '<'},
  controller: function() {
    //...
  }
})
```

**After**

```
.component('myComponent', {
  bindings: {value: '<'},
  controller: function() {
    this.$onInit = function() {
      // ...
    };
  }
})
```

I already discovered that I have to use the same **$onInit** function for any directive using **bindToController: true** like here:

```
.directive('acAllocation', acAllocation);

  function acAllocation(SomeService) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        allocation: '=acAllocation'
      },
      controller: acAllocationController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true,
      templateUrl: 'path/acAllocation.html'
    };

    function acAllocationController() {

      var vm = this;

      this.$onInit = function () { //...
```

Are there any other types of bindings which are affected by this change?

Or is it enough to deal with **components** and **directives with bindToController:true**?

Rephrasing the same question: In an Angular 1.7 application only using **directives with bindToController: false**: can I face any issues regarding pre-assigning bindings at all?

Comment: Be aware that the AngularJS team recommends the `replace: true` property be avoided. For more information, see [Why is `replace` property deprecated in AngularJS directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35545445/5535245).

Comment: Going forward bi-directional binding with `=` should be avoided. It makes the migration to Angular 2+ difficult. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).

Comment: Short answer is that it affects all isolate scope bindings whether they are bound to either the scope or the controller. I will write a more in depth answer later.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated. But we started application long ago and will stay on 1.x during LTS support.

Answer (score 0):

The bindings are complete when $onInit() lifecycle method is called. This is the only guarantee. It's no longer safe to assume that values are available in the constructor, and this affects the entire application.

I would recommend moving to 1.5 style components and ES6 in order to make migration easier in the future.